# Desktop app does not work, but the script in the command works

Tags: python-3.x, linux, user-interface, tkinter, desktop

I have a problem with desktop application. I created desktop app many times and it always works. But now after I created it and then ran it - instead mouse cursor is something like crosshair and files with the names of the imported modules are created inside the folder. [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E00PJ.png). I thing it shouldn't be a problem with the script, because it would write "Failed to execute script ...". I dont know what to do and I didn't find anything similar on google, so I write here.

[Desktop application script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIQBy.png):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version = 1.0
Name = Image Scale
Exec= /home/tucna/ImageScale/ImageScale-cz-Linux.py
Icon = /home/tucna/ImageScale/logo.png
Type = Application
Terminal = false
StartupNotify = false
Path = /home/tucna/ImageScale/
```

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing space before and after the = character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511)

Comment: Of course I forgot to type ```#!/usr/bin/env python3```... Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider to close the question as duplicate.